# Create Dataframe issue in Pyspark from Windows 10

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, hadoop-2.7.2

I am unable to execute the below command from pyspark windows

```
schemaPeople = spark.createDataFrame(people)
```

I have set HADOOP_HOME to winutils
I have provide 77 permission to C:/tmp/hive

Still I am getting the below error -

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o23.applySchemaToPythonRDD.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:189)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive(HiveSharedState.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:46)
```

I have gone through a lot of similar questions before posting this , appreciate any help here

Answer (score 0):

I got this error a bunch when trying to setup Spark on windows using the winutils file. I had to setup Spark differently to get around this.

I ended up downloading the Hadoop binary for my version of spark and going from there. I documented the whole thing with a walkthrough if you are interested. [Spark on windows](https://github.com/GrierPhillips/new_machine_setup/blob/master/spark_windows_setup.md)

The gist is that the official Hadoop release from Apache does not include a Windows binary and compiling from sources can be tedious so really helpful people have made compiled distributions available. If you want to use Spark 2.0.2 download the binaries from [steve loughran's github](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils) for 2.1.0 you can download from [here](https://github.com/karthikj1/Hadoop-2.7.1-Windows-64-binaries/) from there you should be able to set it up as expected.